# New Line in velocity set directive

Tags: macros, velocity

How do you append a newline in velocity template using set? This does not work.

```
#(set $some = "$a \n $b")
```

Prints literally \n.

Doing this also does not work :

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("esc", new EscapeTool());
Velocity.evaluate(context, writer, "LOG", template);
```

Comment: WTF is velocity? You might want to give more context.

Comment: @leppie: Apache Velocity - it's a template engine. @fastcodejava: Why do you need a linebreak in your string? Just write the linebreak directly into the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$esc.n` or its synonym `$esc.newline` from the [EscapeTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/EscapeTool.html) for this:

```
#set($some = $a + $esc.n + $b)
```

How to init tools:

```
ToolManager velocityToolManager = new ToolManager();
velocityToolManager.configure("velocity-tools.xml");
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext(velocityToolManager.createContext());
```

You can get default velocity-tools.xml from [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/velocity/tools/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/tools.xml?view=co&revision=740380&content-type=text%2Fplain) (it's also included into tools jar) and enable tools that you need.

Comment: @serg - Thanks. How do I add `EscapeTool` to context? I did `context.put("esc", new EscapeTool())`. It did not work. This is not a web app, just a plain java code with velocity macro.

Comment: @fastcodejava because it is not the right way to initialize tools. Why not just use what I posted in the answer?

Comment: Why doesn't velocity have \n?

Answer (score 3):

You know, in modern versions of Velocity you just put the line break in.

```
#set( $haslinebreak = "this has
a line break" )
```